# Getting ngShow to work using boolean values

Tags: angularjs, controller

Really sorry for the simple question but for some reason I can not get this simple thing working in a website. I don't think I quite understand how the controller is assigned to a block of html. Here is what I have

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>
    <style media="screen">
        body {
            font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
            background: #ECEFF1;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        }

        a {
            color: rgb(3, 155, 229);
        }

        #message {
            max-width: 400px;
            margin: 40px auto;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
            border-radius: 2px;
            background: white;
            padding: 16px 24px;
        }

        #message h1 {
            font-size: 22px;
            font-weight: 500;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 0 16px;
        }

        #message p {
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: 150%;
        }

        #message ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 16px 0 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #message li a {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 8px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: 500;
            background: rgb(3, 155, 229);
            color: white;
            border: 1px solid rgb(3, 155, 229);
            border-radius: 3px;
            font-size: 14px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .26);
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="portfolio">
    <div id="message" ng-controller="portCtrl">
        <div ng-show="main">Main</div>
        <div ng-show="resume">Resume</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('portfolio', []).controller('portCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.main = true;
    $scope.resume = false;
}]);
```

For the controller, I am using the stronger declaration I found on W3 schools however I ran into the same issue without using the additional ['$scope'] wrapper.

I expect the word Main to display and the word Resume to be hidden, however they are both displayed.

Comment: You forgot to include a `<script>` tag for `app.js`

Comment: seems to be working fine.make sure to add module script to your html ` <script src="script.js"></script> ` [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/XFPksZXiRwKTUove34iy?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the jQuery script reference ?
If you did not include it, just find a jQuery version 1.10 reference link from a cdn or download the file by yourself.
Then set the reference links as below:

- jQuery script
- angularjs script
- your script file should be included below angularjs as well

If you did all of that just let me know so I can help you out with something else.

Comment: There is no need to add `jQuery` here.  Angular includes a lite copy of `jQuery` and he is not using any `jQuery` in his code.